# C# Linq SQL get results where ID not in table

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a script that periodically pulls rows from a database and does stuff with them. But the rows it pulls need to have not been pulled before.

To do this, I use a separate database where I keep the IDs that I've pulled before.
But I have no idea if my solution will actually scale when the list of IDs grows?

```
using (FirstDatabase db = new FirstDatabase())
using (DatabaseWithIDs dbWithIDs = new DatabaseWithIDs())
{
     List<ItemsToProcess> items = db.Items
         .Where(x => x.IWantThis == true ) //conditions to get items from first database
         .Where(x => !dbWithIDs.TableWithIDs.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id) )
         .Select(x => new ItemsToProcess() {x.Id}) //etc.
}
```

Will this scale when the list of IDs grows?

Is there a better way to do this or should I take a completely different approach?

Comment: How do you pull rows from the database?  Randomly or sequentially?

Comment: if you do sequentially,  you can simply store a `rowIndex` variable somewhere in your application then when next you are fetching a row, you fetch the row at `rowIndex + 1`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way to do this

Yes, there is; instead of saving IDs that's been pulled else where, you'd rather consider adding an extra column on the original table to indicate whether or not this row was pulled before. You'd then build your query where this flag equals `0` or `false` or whatever value that indicates that the row hasn't been pulled before; and after every query, you should check whether the query returned any rows; if so, perform an update operation using the same conditions you used in the recently sent query to update the flag to the value that indicates that it's been pulled before.

Comment: The reason for this is a temporary one, to bridge the gap between a legacy database and a new one, so I wanted something where I can just drop the database at the end rather than alter the new one. That's why I've gone down this route rather than the "processed" column one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use `Any` and there isn't any reason need to use `where` twice.

```
using (DatabaseWithIDs dbWithIDs = new DatabaseWithIDs())
{
     List<ItemsToProcess> items = db.Items
         .Where(x => x.IWantThis && dbWithIDs.TableWithIDs.Any(y=>y.Id != x.Id)) //conditions to get items from first database
         .Select(x => new ItemsToProcess() {x.Id}) //etc.
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `All` instead of `Any` ?

Comment: I used `.Where()` multiple times because it makes it easier to read and I think it compiles down to the same query ... I'll debug both my current method and your suggestion to see if they result in different statements.